# How to display all reviews for a specific product using JSTL <c:forEach> tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have set up a form that successfully insert a user product review into database. Now i'm trying to display all the reviews for the given product using `c:forEach` but it does not work. Basically im trying to tell the program `for each selected product get productReviews` but it returns blank. I have 3 classes (`ProductReview`, `ProductHasReview`, `ProductHasReviewPK`) that take care of holding the setter/getter methods as well as the session Beans for the entities.

Servlet

```
        import entity.ProductHasReview;
        import entity.Product;
        import java.util.Collection;
        import javax.ejb.EJB;
    import session.ProductFacade;

        @EJB
            private ProductFacade productFacade;

@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

        String userPath = request.getServletPath();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        Collection<ProductHasReview> productReview = null;

        // if product page is requested
                } else if (userPath.equals("/viewProduct")) {

                    String productId = request.getQueryString();

                    if (productId != null) {

                        // get selected product
                        selectedProduct = productFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(productId));

                        // place selected product in session scope
                        session.setAttribute("selectedProduct", selectedProduct);

                        // get all reviews for selected products
                        productReview = selectedProduct.getProductHasReviewCollection();

                        // place  products reviews in session scope
                        session.setAttribute("productReview", productReview);

                    }

                    userPath = "/product";
```

Product.jsp

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${productReview}"  varStatus="iter">
<div class="content ProdReviewRow">

                <h3>${productReview.name}, ${productReview.age}, ${productReview.gender} </h3>
                <h6>${productReview.dateCreated}<h6>    
                ${productReview.review}    
            </div>
            </c:forEach>
```

Product.java

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;


@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByPrice", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.price = :price"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByLastUpdate", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.lastUpdate = :lastUpdate")})
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 16777215)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdate;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "faq")
    private String faq;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productCollection")
    private Collection<Category> categoryCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Collection<ProductHasBadRating> productHasBadRatingCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Collection<OrderedProduct> orderedProductCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Collection<ProductHasGoodRating> productHasGoodRatingCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Collection<ProductHasReview> productHasReviewCollection;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Product(Integer id, String name, BigDecimal price, String description, Date lastUpdate, String faq) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
        this.faq = faq;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public String getFaq() {
        return faq;
    }

    public void setFaq(String faq) {
        this.faq = faq;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Category> getCategoryCollection() {
        return categoryCollection;
    }

    public void setCategoryCollection(Collection<Category> categoryCollection) {
        this.categoryCollection = categoryCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<ProductHasBadRating> getProductHasBadRatingCollection() {
        return productHasBadRatingCollection;
    }

    public void setProductHasBadRatingCollection(Collection<ProductHasBadRating> productHasBadRatingCollection) {
        this.productHasBadRatingCollection = productHasBadRatingCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<OrderedProduct> getOrderedProductCollection() {
        return orderedProductCollection;
    }

    public void setOrderedProductCollection(Collection<OrderedProduct> orderedProductCollection) {
        this.orderedProductCollection = orderedProductCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<ProductHasGoodRating> getProductHasGoodRatingCollection() {
        return productHasGoodRatingCollection;
    }

    public void setProductHasGoodRatingCollection(Collection<ProductHasGoodRating> productHasGoodRatingCollection) {
        this.productHasGoodRatingCollection = productHasGoodRatingCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<ProductHasReview> getProductHasReviewCollection() {
        return productHasReviewCollection;
    }

    public void setProductHasReviewCollection(Collection<ProductHasReview> productHasReviewCollection) {
        this.productHasReviewCollection = productHasReviewCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Product)) {
            return false;
        }
        Product other = (Product) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Product[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

ProductReview.java

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "product_review")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductReview.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductReview p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductReview.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductReview p WHERE p.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductReview.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductReview p WHERE p.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductReview.findByDateCreated", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductReview p WHERE p.dateCreated = :dateCreated"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductReview.findByCountry", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductReview p WHERE p.country = :country"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductReview.findByAge", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductReview p WHERE p.age = :age"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductReview.findByGender", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductReview p WHERE p.gender = :gender"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductReview.findByEmail", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductReview p WHERE p.email = :email")})
public class ProductReview implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Lob
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "review")
    private String review;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "date_created")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateCreated;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "age")
    private String age;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productReview")
    private Collection<ProductHasReview> productHasReviewCollection;

    public ProductReview() {
    }

    public ProductReview(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getReview() {
        return review;
    }

    public void setReview(String review) {
        this.review = review;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<ProductHasReview> getProductHasReviewCollection() {
        return productHasReviewCollection;
    }

    public void setProductHasReviewCollection(Collection<ProductHasReview> productHasReviewCollection) {
        this.productHasReviewCollection = productHasReviewCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof ProductReview)) {
            return false;
        }
        ProductReview other = (ProductReview) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.ProductReview[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

ProductHasReview.java

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author PC
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_has_review")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductHasReview.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductHasReview p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductHasReview.findByProductId", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductHasReview p WHERE p.productHasReviewPK.productId = :productId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductHasReview.findByProductReviewId", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductHasReview p WHERE p.productHasReviewPK.productReviewId = :productReviewId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductHasReview.findByQuantity", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductHasReview p WHERE p.quantity = :quantity")})
public class ProductHasReview implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected ProductHasReviewPK productHasReviewPK;
    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Short quantity;
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product product;
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_review_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private ProductReview productReview;

    public ProductHasReview() {
    }

    public ProductHasReview(ProductHasReviewPK productHasReviewPK) {
        this.productHasReviewPK = productHasReviewPK;
    }

    public ProductHasReview(int productId, int productReviewId) {
        this.productHasReviewPK = new ProductHasReviewPK(productId, productReviewId);
    }

    public ProductHasReviewPK getProductHasReviewPK() {
        return productHasReviewPK;
    }

    public void setProductHasReviewPK(ProductHasReviewPK productHasReviewPK) {
        this.productHasReviewPK = productHasReviewPK;
    }

    public Short getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Short quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public ProductReview getProductReview() {
        return productReview;
    }

    public void setProductReview(ProductReview productReview) {
        this.productReview = productReview;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (productHasReviewPK != null ? productHasReviewPK.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof ProductHasReview)) {
            return false;
        }
        ProductHasReview other = (ProductHasReview) object;
        if ((this.productHasReviewPK == null && other.productHasReviewPK != null) || (this.productHasReviewPK != null && !this.productHasReviewPK.equals(other.productHasReviewPK))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.ProductHasReview[ productHasReviewPK=" + productHasReviewPK + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Define "does not work". What happens precisely? Why is everything inside the div commented out in the first place? Also, why do you store everything in the session, instead of storing it in the request, where it belongs? And why do you name "ProductHasReview" a product review, instead of "ProductReview"? Why do you name "productReview" a collection of product reviews, instead of "productReviews". This sounds like minor things, but they're hugely important to your own understandability of the code.

Comment: Proof: you used `productReview` in the JSP instead of using `product`. Just because your variables have a bad name. If you had used `<c:forEach var="productReview" items="${productReviews}">`, you probably wouldn't have made this mistake. Because `productReviews`immediately says "I'm in plural form, so I'm not a product review, but a collection or product reviews".

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks for replying.  What I mean by not working is nothing displays. Say I pick product 180 from the category page. The program directs me to its product page with its description, price and addToCart buttons as in any product page. I fill up the product review form to review product 180. I press "post review" and the data is being sent to the database. Fine work greats. But when I look at the comment section for product 180, although the review is recorded in the database, It does not display on the page.

Comment: I forgot to remove the comment out before posting the snippet. My bad, I will update my question. ProductHasReview is the 3rd table that was created from a @OneToMany relationship between table ProductReview and table Product. ProductReview entity is mapped by productReview, it was done automatically when I imported the entities and the sessions from database. I will update my answer for you to see the classes.

Comment: `else if (userPath.equals("/viewProduct"))` is handled by HTTP GET request... and reviewProduct (which is not display here) is handled by HTTP POST request then sent to a Session Bean Manager that take cares of the getters/setters.

Comment: @JBNizet: If you take a look at Product.java, this is what I'm trying to call: `private Collection<ProductHasReview> productHasReviewCollection;` which is mapped by `product` which is the same for the ProductReview.java and that particular class is mapped by `productReview`. I understand the importance of naming the variables the right way I will update my code. As for `<c:forEach var="productReview" items="${productReviews}">`, how would it actually know i'm trying to get the reviews for say product 180 and not the entire collection of reviews if the var isn't product?